# Issue : Text get cut while using break word

Tags: html

At the time of add story, I have given ckeditor to add experience details & advice section. But at the time of display it goes out of scope for that we have used "word-wrap: break-word;". Using this text get cut like my text is "cool" it displays "co" & to new line "ol"

Please clienk on below link, you will see "Experience Details" & "My Advice" section. In "Experience Details" section text get cut in the sentence "I don't smoke. Never did.  There was plenty of peer pressure to start.  Growing up the cool kids did it.  My parents did it.".

http://www.techmodi.com/demo/firstjitters/story/MTQz/readStory

I want to resolve this text cut issue. Please suggest me solution if anybody have.

Comment: what's the intention? why do you want a word-wrap there?

Comment: If I remove the word wrap then it display all the text in single line. Even you can check that...inspect with firebug & remove word wrap.

Comment: take the width off .advisebox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace &nbsp with space. like this.

```
  $string = str_replace("&nbsp"," ", $string);
```

Must work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `&nbsp;` in the text you want to be shown on multiple lines. Just replace the `&nbsp` with just a space char (`" "`) everywhere you want the text to break onto the new line.

Answer (score 1):

The `&nbsp;` is causing this.

Replace it with " " with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)